# How can I read just one line from standard input, and pass the rest to a subprocess?

Tags: python, input, subprocess

If you `readline()` from `sys.stdin`, passing the rest of it to a subprocess does not seem to work.

```
import subprocess
import sys

header = sys.stdin.buffer.readline()
print(header)
subprocess.run(['nl'], check=True)
```

(I'm using `sys.stdin.buffer` to avoid any encoding issues; this handle returns the raw bytes.)

This runs, but I don't get any output from the subprocess;

```
bash$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | python demo1.py
b'foo\n'
```

If I take out the `readline` etc, the subprocess reads standard input and produces the output I expect.

```
bash$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz |
> python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.run(["nl"], check=True)'
     1  foo
     2  bar
     3  baz
```

Is Python buffering the rest of stdin when I start reading it, or what's going on here? Running with `python -u` does not remove the problem (and indeed, the documentation for it only mentions that it changes the behavior for `stdout` and `stderr`). But if I pass in a larger amount of data, I do get some of it:

```
bash$ wc -l /etc/services
   13921 /etc/services

bash$ python demo1.py </etc/services  | head -n 3
     1     27/tcp     # NSW User System FE
     2  #                          Robert Thomas <BThomas@F.BBN.COM>
     3  #                28/tcp    Unassigned
 (... traceback from broken pipe elided ...)

bash$  fgrep -n 'NSW User System FE' /etc/services 
91:nsw-fe           27/udp     # NSW User System FE
92:nsw-fe           27/tcp     # NSW User System FE

bash$ sed -n '1,/NSW User System FE/p' /etc/services | wc
      91     449    4082
```

(So, looks like it eats 4096 bytes from the beginning.)

Is there a way I can avoid this behavior, though? I would like to only read one line off from the beginning, and pass the rest to the subprocess.

Calling `sys.stdin.buffer.readline(-1)` repeatedly in a loop does not help.

This is actually a follow-up for [Read line from shell pipe, pass to exec, and keep to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940345/read-line-from-shell-pipe-pass-to-exec-and-keep-to-variable) but I wanted to focus on this, to me, surprising aspect of the problem in that question.

Comment: No.  Part of this comes from Python, part of this comes from C runtime library, part of this comes from the operating system.  You can't control most of those.  So, read everything yourself and use `subprocess.PIPE` to copy it in to the process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `sys.stdin` is [created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2287) using the built-in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function in the default buffered mode, which uses a buffer of size `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`, which on most systems is either `4096` or `8192` bytes.

To make the parent process consume precisely one line of text from the standard input, you can therefore open it with the buffer disabled by passing `0` as the `buffering` argument to the `open` or `os.fdopen` function:

```
# subp1.py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# or with the platform-dependent device file:
# unbuffered_stdin = open('/dev/stdin', 'rb', buffering=0)
unbuffered_stdin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', buffering=0)

print(unbuffered_stdin.readline())
subprocess.run(['nl'], check=True)
```

so that:

```
printf "foo\nbar\n" | python subp1.py
```

would then output:

```
b'foo\n'
     1  bar
```